# Getting the subnet and class of an IPv4 or and IPv6 address

Tags: python, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I want to make a project that gets the subnet mask and the class that an Ip address belongs to. nothing happens after the hosts are displayed. Any help would be appreciated!

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork
import ipaddress

option = input("Do you want to work with an IPv4 or an IPv6 address ? ")

# gets all usable hosts for an IPv4 address
if option == "IPv4":
    IPv4_Address = input("Enter an IPv4 address: ")
    print("Printing usable hosts: \n")

    for ip in IPNetwork(IPv4_Address):
        print(ip)

    # gets the Ip address class

    print("Getting the IPv4 address class \n")

    classA = ipaddress.IPv4Network(("10.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0"))
    classB = ipaddress.IPv4Network(("172.16.0.0", "255.240.0.0"))
    classC = ipaddress.IPv4Network(("192.168.0.0", "255.255.0.0"))

    if IPv4_Address in classA:
        print("The IPv4 address is a Class A address.")
    elif IPv4_Address in classB:
        print("The IPv4 address is a Class B address")
    elif IPv4_Address in classC:
        print("The IPv4 address is a Class C address. ")
    else:
        print("Not valid ip address")


# gets all usable hosts for an IPv6 address
elif option == "IPv6":
    IPv6_Address = input("Enter an IPv6 address: ")
    print("Printing usable hosts: \n")
    for ip in IPNetwork(IPv6_Address):
        print(ip)

else:
    print("not valid")
```

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years before the commercial Internet in 1995) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). We have not had classful networking in this century, and IPv6 has never had network classes.

Comment: In any case, [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/51918/8499) explains what the network classes used to be, which is very different than what you have. Also, with a couple of exceptions, standard IPv6 networks should be `/64`, and that means there are `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` possible addresses in the network, and it would take you over `584,542` years! to list them at `1,000,000` addresses per second.